# Bar chart with first each month while having different durations

Tags: excel, vba, bar-chart

After publishing a too broad question in the first place, I want to ask for a second time – more problem-focused.
The shown bar chart is needed for a broad variety of projects and will be used for 6 month projects as well as for 3 year projects. 
But it will be forwarded – so it should look professional.
For this reason I want to change the dates on the x-axis to the first of every month. For a fixed period of time, I would be able to do so. But for a broad variety of durations, it’ll have to have some vba code in the background – and that’s where I’m dipping in the dark. All my testing with start and end date didn’t work out. There’s too much variety in these numbers.

I’ll show the vba of the chart down below. It’s just recorded and has no special tricks inside.

Is there a way, to get there? With calculation between start and end date, I didn’t get a reliable result for first of each month for a random time period.

Thanks for your help! <3

[image: Source and bar chart. Note: dates are dd.mm.yy]

```
Sub testStackoverflow()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarStacked
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("testStckoverflow!$A$86:$B$96")
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 3").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you perhaps create a pivotchart and then use a timeline slicer?

Comment: maybe... but the daily user is on average older than me and could be confused. I want to minimize this possibility by making it as "standard" as they are used to know. In the end it's all about how much the user likes to use it :( thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a 2D horizontal stacked bar chart.

Set the start of the chart's x-axis as the first day of the earliest month that appears in the project schedule.

Series 1 for each task is the difference between the task start date and the date which starts the chart's x-axis. This allows you to show tasks which don't all start at the same date. Set the bar portion for this series to transparent.

Series 2 for each task is the task duration in days. This portion of each bar should be set to be visible.

Format the X-axis of the chart to Category: Date, Type: Month-Year. This will set each tick to the first day of each month.

[Formatted bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rccyT.png)

Comment: while your suggestion can be a solution, but to support that as answer you need to post relevant codes as well. Otherwise this is better as comment ...

Comment: I wanted to post it as a comment but don't have enough reputation. This is my first post. It sounds like what they want to do is well supported by features already in excel, and no code is necessary. In that case, is an answer without code inappropriate? Thanks!

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your first answer ever here :) Also thanks for the duration - that's basically, what we are doing. We've also build a process percentage in there - but all of this is off Topic. But thanks for sharing the idea anyway! <3                  Back to the main point: Your picture already shows, that this solution just cuts off the day from the date. What I need is, that it only sets a new tick really every first of each month. (Otherways your not able to see, whether the action should be finished at the end or at the beginning of March.) But thanks for the reply nevertheless!